# If you prove a proposition for a singleton set in $\{x\} \in P(X)$ will it automatically follow $ \forall X \in P(X)$ ? Is this the best approach?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Imagine if you have to prove a general statement for all sets in a power set:

$$\forall X \in P(X) : P \implies Q.$$

Is it a good idea to use the fact that all sets in $P(X)$ are unions of singleton sets? I.e.,

$$X = \bigcup_{x_i\in X}\{x_i\}.$$

Also what is the proper notation to use to show what you are exactly doing without being too vague?

1. Prove $P \implies Q$ for a random chosen singleton $\{x_i\}$
2. Since any set $X$ is the union of these singletons, it follows that $P \implies Q$ for all $X$

Any pitfalls? I guess you should not forget the empty set $\emptyset$.  Sometimes it is very easy to prove something for a single element, so I hope this is possible.

Is this the 'best' approach to these problems?

**My specific questions**

1. If you prove a proposition for a singleton set in $\{x\} \in P(X)$ will it automatically follow $ \forall X \in P(X)$?
2. Is this the best approach?

Comment: What about the property of being a singleton?

Comment: I have no idea whether it's a "good" idea to use the fact that $X=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$, because I have no idea _how_ one might "use" this.

Comment: (No, proving something for every singleton certainly doesn't prove anything for every subset...)

Comment: Singletons are **not** empty, while the empty set is empty. Thus, it is not ture that **every** property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a counterexample for you to work on. Suppose the we want to prove the (false) statement
$$\forall X \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \quad X \neq \emptyset \implies \exists a \in \mathbb{N} \colon \; a = \max{X}.$$

This statement is clearly false, just take $\mathbb{N}$ itself. Although, you can prove that the above result is true for each singleton in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. The only element in each singleton will be the maximum.

Therefore, no. In general, you cannot prove a general property for arbitrary sets of a power set, by proving that the results holds for each singleton.